# Go mod tidy from internal repo via ssh failing

Tags: go, github, github-actions

I cannot `go mod tidy` when using an internal GitHub repo. SSH auth seems to work in isolation (see log below) but the `go mod tidy` hits the internal repo and throws

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

From my Github action

```
steps:
            # Checks-out the repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so the job can access it
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3

            # Set up Go
            - name: Set up Go
              uses: actions/setup-go@v4
              with:
                  go-version: 1.20.2
                  cache: false

            - name: Add private key to SSH agent
              env:
                PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SHARED_DEPLOY_PRIVATE_KEY }}
              run: |
                echo "${{ env.PRIVATE_KEY }}" > key.pem
                chmod 600 key.pem
                eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
                ssh-add key.pem
                ssh-add -l -E sha256
                ssh -T git@github.com 2>&1 || true    ### tests ssh auth

            # Install dependencies
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: |
                  git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
                  go clean -modcache  
                  go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/my-org/*
                  go env -w GONOPROXY=github.com/my-org/*
                  go env
                  go mod tidy
```

Log for `Add private key`

```
Agent pid 1766
Identity added: key.pem (_REDACTED_)
3072 SHA256:_REDACTED_ _REDACTED_ (RSA)
Hi my-org/observability-go! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Log for `Install dependencies`

```
go: downloading github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.17
go: downloading golang.org/x/sync v0.1.0
github.com/my-org/clan-service/cmd/clanservice imports
    github.com/my-org/observability-go/logging: github.com/my-org/observability-go@v0.0.0-20230623103942-2be438a81907: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/d0c7f50097d6054d27fc7949420737cdb6036d1246584bb05f13c6fe75577be2: exit status 128:
    git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Output from `go env`

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/runner/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/runner/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/runner/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY="github.com/my-org/*"
GONOSUMDB="github.com/my-org/*"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/runner/go"
GOPRIVATE="github.com/my-org/*"
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.20.2/x64"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.20.2/x64/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.20.2"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/runner/work/clan-service/clan-service/go.mod"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_FFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-O2 -g"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build4021260014=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

What have I missed? How do I make this work?

Comment: shouldn't you re-run the environment setup in your second step ? the environment variables set by the first `"eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` will probably not survive the change of process between the two steps

Comment: change your comment to an answer, and you win a prize ;)

Comment: it would never have occurred to me this wouldn't persist, you've saved me from the abyss :keanu-thanks:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each step is run in a separate process, so actions which modify the environment for the scope of the current process will not "survive" to the next step.

For example:
you would need to re-run `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` in your "Install dependencies" step, so that the environment is set up correctly to talk to your ssh agent.